# Is the matrix of a linear operator invertible iff it can be row reduced to an upper triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that wrt some basis of V, if the matrix of a linear operator L(V) is upper triangular (assuming no zeros in the diagonal) then the matrix is invertible.

My question is, if the matrix of L(V) wrt some basis of V is not upper triangular but can be row reduced to this form, is this matrix still guaranteed to be invertible given that there are no zeros in the diagonal of the row reduced upper triangular matrix?

Comment: When you row reduce a matrix, you multiply it by some invertible matrix from the left side. So the original matrix is invertible if and only if the matrix you obtain after row reducing is invertible.

Comment: @Mark So the answer is yes, I’m assuming? I’m looking for a quick easy way to prove injectivity and surjectivity and thought this was a cool way.

Comment: I got concerned this wasn’t  the case when I figured out eigenvalues aren’t along the diagonal when the matrix is row reduced to an UT matrix, though I do know they are multiples of the product of the diagonal in this case.

Comment: The answer is yes in the sense that row reducing preserves invertible matrices, which is what you asked. But clearly row reducing doesn't preserve the eigenvalues. Don't get confused between row reducing and matrix similarity.

Comment: So if I have a matrix wrt to a basis that is not upper triangular, then I row reduce it to an upper triangular matrix with no zeros in the diagonal, then I know my original matrix is guaranteed to be invertible, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.